# C# Array isn't holding data

Tags: c#, generator

I'm trying to create a dungeon generator for a project I've been working on based off of this [algorithm](http://bigbadwofl.blogspot.com/2012/12/random-dungeon-generation.html). I've gotten everything down, but my array (Fig. 1) doesn't seem to be holding giving the map data for some reason. I'm using three types of data to determine if a cell in the map is either empty (0), a space a character can be on (1), a hallway (2), or a wall (3).

I've gotten a bit stuck on this portion so any help is appreciated!

EDIT: The problem is the map object isn't storing the data in the loop shown in Fig. 1. Sorry for being so vague.

(Fig. 1)

```
        for (int i = 0; i < roomList.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int x = roomList[i].X; x < (roomList[i].X + roomList[i].W); x++)
            {
                for (int y = roomList[i].Y; y < (roomList[i].Y + roomList[i].H); y++)
                {
                    map[x, y] = 1;
                }
            }
        }
```

(All of my relevant code)

```
namespace Project
{
    }
    public class Room
    {
        int xValue, yValue, widthValue, heightValue;

        public int X
        {
            get { return xValue; }
            set { xValue = value; }
        }
        public int Y
        {
            get { return yValue; }
            set { yValue = value; }
        }
        public int W
        {
            get { return widthValue; }
            set { widthValue = value; }
        }
        public int H
        {
            get { return heightValue; }
            set { heightValue = value; }
        }
    }
public class DungeonGenerate
{
    public int baseWidth = 513;
    public int baseHeight = 513;
    public int width = 64;
    public int height = 64;
    Color[,] arrayColor;
    Random rand = new Random();
    Room room = new Room();
    Rectangle[,] rectMap;

    public void Generate()
    {
        rectMap = new Rectangle[baseWidth, baseHeight];
        //Creates a 2-D Array/Grid for the Dungeon
        int[,] map = new int[baseWidth, baseHeight];
        //Determines all the cells to be empty until otherwise stated
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
            {
                map[x, y] = 0;
            }
        }

        //Determines the amount of rooms in the dungeon
        int minRooms = (width * height) / 300;
        int maxRooms = (width * height) / 150;
        int amountOfRooms = rand.Next(minRooms, maxRooms);

        //Room dimensions
        int widthRoot = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Round(Math.Sqrt(width * 2)));
        int heightRoot = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Round(Math.Sqrt(height * 2)));
        int minWidth = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Round((width * .5) / widthRoot));
        int maxWidth = Convert.ToInt32((width * 2) / widthRoot);
        int minHeight = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Round(height * .5) / heightRoot);
        int maxHeight = Convert.ToInt32((height * 2) / heightRoot);

        //Creates the rooms
        List<Room> roomList = new List<Room>(amountOfRooms);

        for (int i = 0; i < amountOfRooms; i++)
        {
            bool ok = false;
            do
            {
                room.X = rand.Next(width);
                room.Y = rand.Next(height);
                room.W = (rand.Next(maxWidth)) + minWidth;
                room.H = (rand.Next(maxHeight)) + minHeight;

                if (room.X + room.W >= width && room.Y + room.H >= height)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                for (int q = 0; q < roomList.Count; q++)
                {
                    if (room.X > roomList[q].X && room.X < roomList[q].X + room.W && room.Y > roomList[q].Y && room.Y < roomList[q].Y + room.H)
                    {
                        ok = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                ok = true;
                roomList.Add(room);
            } while (!ok);
        }
        //This will create hallways that lead to and from the rooms
        int connectionCount = roomList.Count;
        List<Point> connectedCells = new List<Point>((width * height));
        for (int i = 0; i < connectionCount; i++)
        {
            Room roomA = roomList[i];
            int roomNum = i;

            while (roomNum == i)
            {
                roomNum = rand.Next(roomList.Count);
            }

            Room roomB = roomList[roomNum];

            //Increasing this will make the hallway more straight, decreasing it will make the hallway more skewed
            int sidestepChance = 10;

            Point pointA = new Point(x: (rand.Next(roomA.W)) + roomA.X, y: (rand.Next(roomA.H)) + roomA.Y);
            Point pointB = new Point(x: (rand.Next(roomB.W)) + roomB.X, y: (rand.Next(roomB.H)) + roomB.Y);

            while (pointA != pointB)
            {
                int num = rand.Next() * 100;

                if (num < sidestepChance)
                {
                    if (pointB.X != pointA.X)
                    {
                        if (pointB.X > pointA.X)
                        {
                            pointB.X--;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            pointB.X++;
                        }
                    }
                }
                else if(pointB.Y != pointA.Y)
                {
                    if (pointB.Y > pointA.Y)
                    {
                        pointB.Y--;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        pointB.Y++;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (pointB.X < width && pointB.Y < height)
            {
                connectedCells.Add(pointB);
            }
        }

        //Fills the room with data
        for (int i = 0; i < roomList.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int x = roomList[i].X; x < (roomList[i].X + roomList[i].W); x++)
            {
                for (int y = roomList[i].Y; y < (roomList[i].Y + roomList[i].H); y++)
                {
                    map[x, y] = 1;
                }
            }
        }

        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
            {
                if (map[x, y] == 0)
                {
                    bool wall = false;
                    for (int yy = y - 2; yy < y + 2; yy++)
                    {
                        for (int xx = x - 2; xx < x + 2; xx++)
                        {
                            if (xx > 0 && yy > 0 && xx < width && yy < height)
                            {
                                if (map[xx, yy] == 1 || map[xx, yy] == 2)
                                {
                                    map[x, y] = 3;
                                    wall = true;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        if (wall)
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        //Rendering the Map and giving it some Color (Sort of)!
        int scaler = baseWidth / width;

        for (int x = 0; x < baseWidth; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < baseHeight; y++)
            {
                rectMap[x, y] = new Rectangle(x, y, 1, 1);
                arrayColor = new Color[baseWidth, baseHeight];
                switch (map[x, y])
                {
                    case 0:
                        arrayColor[x, y] = new Color(0,0,0);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        arrayColor[x, y] = new Color(0,0,0);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        arrayColor[x, y] = new Color(0,0,0);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        arrayColor[x, y] = new Color (0,0,0);
                        break; 
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public Rectangle[,] GetMap()
    {
        return rectMap;
    }
    public Color[,] GetColors()
    {
        return arrayColor;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't hold value? Which part exactly?

Comment: Can you try to be a bit more specific about what the problem is?A big list of code and a cryptic question about not holding values doesn't really help us to help you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `for`-loop where you're populating `roomList`, you're not instantiating a new `Room` each time. You're simply manipulating the same `Room` object and re-adding it to the list, so `roomList` will just contain many references to the same `Room` object. Try removing the `room` field from your `DungeonGenerate` class and use a local variable instead:

```
for (int i = 0; i < amountOfRooms; i++)
{
    bool ok = false;
    do
    {
        var room = new Room();
        ...
        roomList.Add(room);
    } while (!ok);
}
```